# local queue on YouTube

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, youtube

This might be a little bit of a weird question but I'm trying to make an extension that updates the youtube queue when you add a video from another window. I was thinking of just remaking the queue for youtube (I know that this would be a large task). How would I manually add a video to this queue?

Answer (score 0):

There are two main problems that need to be solved to add a this feature.

1. Storing and synchronizing the queue.
2. Knowing when a user adds or removes a video in the queue.

Both Firefox and chrome provide extension storage for this purpose and this should solve the first problem.
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage

For the second problem you need to write a content script that will either add your own button to YouTube or override the original add to watch queue button functionality. So that when clicked the url of the video will be added to extension storage.

You could then display the queue in the extension popup and when a video is played a message can be sent to the active window changing the location to the new video like so.

```
// popup.js
chrome.storage.sync.get(['queue'], (result) => {
    const firstInQueue = result.queue.shift();
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {video: firstInQueue}, function(response) {
           chrome.storage.sync.set({queue: result.queue}, () => {
              console.log(`${result.queue.length} videos in queue`);
           });
        });
    });
});


// content.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
    document.location.href = request.video;
});
```

Overriding functionality on an existing site can be difficult and short-lived as if YouTube chooses to update its UI it may break you feature.

Looking at the network tab when adding a video to the queue reveals that a post request is made to `https://www.youtube.com/youtubei/v1/playlist/create` this may be another area to look.

Comment: I didn't really think to check the network tab lol, I actually already went down that path they're making a call to the [youtube data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/insert?hl=en) to create a playlist. I thought that they were keeping an instance of the queue in local storage and that I could manipulate that. This kind of puts a wrench in my plans because I went away from this because I wanted the playlist to update dynamically without pausing the video.